# Which are the incompressible flows around a sphere with no azimuthal vorticity?

Tags: vortex, potential-flow

Assume fluid velocity $\vec{u}(r, θ, φ)$

radial distance: r ≥ 0,
polar angle: 0° ≤ θ ≤ 180° (π rad),
azimuth : 0° ≤ φ < 360° (2π rad).

At r much larger than sphere radius the flow is $\vec{u}=u_0 * (1, 0, φ)$

Incompressible: $\nabla \cdot \vec{u} = 0$

and $(\nabla \times u) \times \hat{\varphi} = 0$, which is the same as not allowing vorticity in the (r, θ) plane.

One solution seems to be to take the entirely irrotational axially symmetric two dimensional solution $\vec{u}_{rθ}(r, θ)$ and add any one dimensional $u_φ(r, θ)$ in the third dimension $\hat{φ}$.

Are there (more) general solutions?

One interesting case is if there are any solutions without axial symmetry ($\vec{u}(r, θ, φ_1) \ne \vec{u}(r, θ, φ_2))$?

I accept weak solutions like Leray non pointwise interval averaged solutions.